# Getting a background image to align center when text-align isn't working in CSS3

Tags: html, wordpress, css

I have a snippet of code in a WordPress widget, where I'm attempting to make an image a background image instead of a regular image

Here's the code:

```
<p><div style="background-image: url('https://www.nationalcdp.org/wp-content/uploads
/2014/09/nationalcdp-600.png');text-align:center!important;background-repeat:no-  
repeat;width=600px;height:316px;"></div></p>
```

For some reasons, the image does show as intended, but continues to align left -- even with the !important.

Here's a Firebug screen capture:

[image: Firebug]

Am I doing something incorrectly here?  If any more information is needed, by all means, just ask.

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you're confusing properties. You need to use it like this:

```
<div style="background: url('https://www.nationalcdp.org/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/nationalcdp-600.png') no-repeat 50% 50%; width:600px; height:316px;"></div>
```

`text-align` will center your content inside the element, just not  your background. See that `50% 50%` (I'm aligning the background in the middle for both vertical and horizontal axises, but you could use something like top center, 0 50%, 20% 10%, 30px 100px or whatever depending on your needs)

You can see the [complete specifications for background position here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-position)

Comment: Thanks, Fabio!  For some reason, the image just isn't showing up at all now.  I did include the height:316px; in your code, as I want it to show above the text / paragraph below it.  But the image isn't showing up for some odd reason.  I appreciate you taking the time to help!

Comment: ah, because I removed the height and width, and since the div is empty, nothing was showing. I edited the answer to add your original sizes and it works as expected , see http://jsfiddle.net/5ecgy824/

Comment: Thanks Fabio!  Well-done.  I just added background-position: center top; ... not sure if I had to, but this is precisely the effect I wanted.  Thanks for taking the time to help, the link, and taking the time to make the fiddle!